# What is the defined value for Settings.System.Clock_Color on ANDROID source code (AOSP)?

Tags: android, android-source

I know it exists, because it is used for applying status_bar clock color, but where is defined the default value for this setting? How can I change Settings.System.Clock_Color?.
I would like to change the color of the clock in the status bar but none of the solutions I've found have shown the source code. Where is this value defined?

Answer (score 1):

In the file `frameworks/base/packages/SystemUI/res/layout/status_bar.xml` there is a definition of the layout of the status bar. You can find in it the definition of clocks:

```
<com.android.systemui.statusbar.Clock
    android:textAppearance="@*android:style/TextAppearance.StatusBar.Icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:paddingRight="6dip"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
    />
```

The clock style is reference to the file `frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/styles.xml` where the style defined in the following way:

```
<!-- Status Bar Styles -->

    <style name="TextAppearance.StatusBar">
        <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">?android:attr/textColorPrimary</item>
    </style>
    <style name="TextAppearance.StatusBar.Ticker">
    </style>
    <style name="TextAppearance.StatusBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    </style>

    <style name="TextAppearance.StatusBar.Icon">
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    </style>
```

There is a reference to `?android:attr/textColorPrimary`. I [found](http://www.manning.com/collins/AiP_sample_ch04.pdf) that this means:

> For example,
>   suppose you want to change the link color to the color Android uses for plain text, but
>   you don’t know that color’s value. Furthermore, the primary text color isn’t exposed
>   as a color resource because it’s variable; it changes with the theme.

So this means that the color of your clocks depends on the textColorPrimary of your theme. Thus, to change this color you should change this value for your themes.